# Android SDK Manager is not running in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using windows7 64bit,jdk7

Solutions that i tried

1. reinstalling the jdk,adt bundle
2. setting the JAVA_HOME,PATH variable also
3. edited the android.bat file
4. deleted the .android from windows folder

Comment: try to run it manually, if so you may not have configured it well, check your ADT plugin

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting any error? Please give more info.

Comment: when i tried running the sdk manager from eclipse i found the error D:\Android\ADT-BU~1\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file. My adt bundle is in d drive

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it manually if it says that tools folder is missing then you may need to download it again, you wont need to reinstall eclipse.
It may be also caused because of different path of your sdk folder. In eclipse go to
 Window -> Preferences -> Android -> and browse to looking for SDK folder.